# MySQL Workbench: Can't apply NOW() to timestamps field

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I get this problem with applying now() to timestamp field. It just doesn't automatically fill in the field with the current time. I tried both now() and NOW() and also current_time, doesn't work either. What can be the problem? What other values I can insert into the field in order to get the current time?
[image]

[image]

Comment: don't put `now()` in quotes

Comment: I didn't, I just typed in plain now(). There are screenshots provided

Comment: My bad. I didn't even pay attention to the query I was applying. That's where I should've removed the quotes. Thank you!

Comment: @ali answer is the correct one.

Comment: Still it is annoying to have to delete quotes when running now() for datetime in mysql workbench

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use now() in query without quotes:

```
Insert into blog.task(body,created_at ,updated_at)values('some values',now(),now());
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I feel stupid now, I haven't even thought about using queries instead of hard coding data. But, still the guy in the tutorial I watched, he typed now() straight into the field without any errors occuring so I might still do some research on this.

Answer (score 61):

If you want to edit data directly in the Result Grid, for functions add "\func" before that function. In this case try this:

```
\func now()
```

it will be now() in the query you will see in Apply SQL Script to Database window.

Comment: I don't know why this is not the accepted answer! Even though it shows exactly what the OP looking for in thus case.

Comment: Exactly the answer the OP and I was looking for. The accepted answer is a workaround but not what was asked by OP. OP just went the "easier/alternative" way around and did exactly what I did not want to do and I think he/she neighter actually.